# Data frame slicing with dynamic column name as variable

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the data data table

```
DT1 = as.data.table(data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3,2,5,1,3,3,1,2), col2 = c(3,4,5,4,3,4,5,3,4,5), col3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)))
```

I would like to column-slice it from variable.

So

```
DT1[, c("col1", "col3")]
```

will work with no problem.
How about slicing from column names stored in variables.

```
col_name1 <- "col1"
col_name2 <- "col3"
```

I have tried `get` but with no luck.

```
DT1[, c(get(col_name1), "col2")]
>[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "2"    "5"    "1"    "3"    "3"    "1"    "2"    "col2"
DT1[, get(c(col_name1, "col2"))]
>[1] 1 2 3 2 5 1 3 3 1 2


DT1[, get(c(col_name1, col_name2))]
 >[1] 1 2 3 2 5 1 3 3 1 2
DT1[, c(get(col_name1), get(col_name2))]
 >[1]  1  2  3  2  5  1  3  3  1  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Any idea ? While we are at it, could you also help me explain the logic behind the unsuccessful approaches that I tried ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.SD` with `.SDcols`

```
DT1[, .SD, .SDcols = c(col_name1, col_name2)]
#    col1 col3
# 1:    1    1
# 2:    2    2
# 3:    3    3
# 4:    2    4
# 5:    5    5
# 6:    1    6
# 7:    3    7
# 8:    3    8
# 9:    1    9
#10:    2   10
```

or (provided `data.table` version `> 1.10.2`)

```
DT1[, c(..col_name1, ..col_name2)]
```

or

```
DT1[, c(col_name1, col_name2), with = F]
```

Note however that the last option will be formally [deprecated in the next few years](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md), and you should use the `..` prefix version instead.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Maurits. Could you also explain to me what went wrong with my approach using `get` ? Also, pre-assigning the list to vector and use `..` will also work `col_list <- c(col_name1, col_name2); DT1[, ..col_list] ` but not `DT1[, ..c(col_name1, col_name2)]`

Comment: You're very welcome @Kenny. As to your questions: From the [FAQ 1.1](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num): In `data.table` "the 2nd argument is an *expression* which is evaluated within the scope of `DT`". `get` on the other hand returns an *object*. Also `..` is a prefix to a *variable* telling `data.table` to look up a variable in the calling scope. Therefore prefixing `c()` with `..` doesn't make sense (as you discovered already).